# How do I block undefined variables from being sent on Postman?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm using Postman to run test on an API using a CSV file as an external file data. In the CSV file, there are multiple data sets with different amount of data, some with data and some without. When I run collection runner and it runs the first data set, it fails because there are variables that have not been defined and the API throws a data error.

In the CSV

1. Data set 1

   - order,
     clientid,
     barcode 1,
     quantity 1,
     unitprice 1
2. Data set 2

   - order,
     clientid,
     barcode 1,
     quantity 1,
     unitprice 1,
     barcode 2,
     quantity 2,
     unitprice 2
3. Data set 3

   - order,
     clientid,
     barcode 1,
     quantity 1,
     unitprice 1,
     barcode 2,
     quantity 2,
     unitprice 2,
     barcode 3,
     quantity 3,
     unitprice 3

```
In the body I've added that extra variables in case it is available in a data set.

{
  "order"  :  "{{orderId}}",
  "clientId" : "{{clientId}}",
  "skus"  :  [
        {
            "barcode": {{barcode1}},
            "quantity": {{quantity1}},
            "unitPrice": {{price1}}
        },
         {
            "barcode": {{barcode2}},
            "quantity": {{quantity2}},
            "unitPrice": {{price2}}
        },
         {
            "barcode": {{barcode3}},
            "quantity": {{quantity3}},
            "unitPrice": {{price3}}
        }
    ]

}
```

This is the response:

```
{
 "order" : "1000305408",
 "clientId" : "30",
 "skus" : [
 {
 "barcode": 123123123,
 "quantity": 1,
 "unitPrice": 100
 },
 {
 "barcode": {{barcode2}},
 "quantity": {{quantity2}},
 "unitPrice": {{price2}}
 }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to block those undefined variable key and data while still having it in the body just in case the new data set has the variable?

Comment: This question is better than 99.9% of the questions posted here.

Comment: haha thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can dynamically find out the number of sets that are present using the CSV file that is uploaded.

I am just checking how many barcode sets are there and using that, I am prepairing a `setCount` which will be used to loop over the data and create `skus` items.

**Pre-request script:**

```
_ = require('lodash');

// Here we'll know how many unit counts we have, I am checking barcode only.
let setCount = _.chain(data) // data is the actual iteration data from the csv file, don't worry just run the script.
    .keys()
    .countBy((item) => item.includes('barcode'))
    .value()
    .true,

    skus = [];


for(var i = 1; i <= setCount; i++) {
    skus.push({
        barcode: data[`barcode${i}`],
        quantity: data[`quantity${i}`],
        unitPrice: data[`unitprice${i}`]
    });
}

let requestBody = {
    order: data["orderId"],
    clientId: data["clientId"],
    skus: skus
};

pm.variables.set('requestBody', JSON.stringify(requestBody));
```

In your request **Body** tab do the following:

Set the body to raw with JSON and add `{{requestBody}}` as the variable in the body.

You can refer the screenshot if any confusion is there.
[image: raw json body]

Comment: I've tried this but for empty variables, it would still go through because it sends a null and gives a data error.

{"skus":[{"barcode":5702015989480,"quantity":1},{"barcode":5702015989480,"quantity":1},{"barcode":null,"quantity":null},{"barcode":null,"quantity":null}]}

Comment: Okay I've added if else barcode just for the null issue and it works! :)

`for(var i = 1; i <= setCount; i++) {
    if (data[`barcode${i}`]){
        skus.push({
        barcode: data[`barcode${i}`],
        quantity: data[`quantity${i}`],
        unitPrice: data[`unitprice${i}`]
    });
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a **Pre-request Script** to create your JSON dynamically.

This would in essence be needed:

```
var body = {
    order : pm.environment.get('orderId'),
    clientId : pm.environment.get('clientId'),
    skus : []
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var barcode = pm.environment.get('barcode' + i);
    if (barcode) {
        var quantity = pm.environment.get('quantity' + i);
        var price = pm.environment.get('price' + i);
        var obj = {
            barcode : barcode,
            quantity : quantity,
            unitPrice : price
        }
        body.skus.push(obj);
    }
}
pm.environment.set('dynamic_json', JSON.stringify(body));
```

Then in the **Body** tab where you normally put fixed JSON, use just this:

```
{{dynamic_json}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with runner and CSV file but works fine when environments are already set